# Интеграция приложения Android с онлайн кассой Атол

Tags: php, c#, android, интеграция

Я разрабатываю приложение для ресторанов, и встал серьезный вопрос с печатью чеков.

Мне нужно подключить планшет Android к кассовому аппарату, и при нажатии на кнопку в моем приложении, онлайн касса должна печатать чек с информацией переданной в запросе. Я изучал Api Атол и связывался с поставщиком. Он ответил, что такая система возможна и реализована в курьерской службе ПониЭкспресс, так же сказал что это делается с помощью сервисных кодов, которые можно вытащить, но как работать с ними не знает.

Вот и стоит вопрос: каким образом возможно сделать интеграцию онлайн кассы Атол с Android устройством? Язык C# либо PHP.

Comment: Я думаю вам нужна некая прослойка между вашим приложением и драйвером Атола(не думаю что можно напрямую). Я бы сделал  например Win-service  с http интерфейсом, через который принимал команды с вашего приложения, а сервис в свою очередь давал команды драйверу атол. Я думаю реализовать эти команды с API драйвера не сложно, доки все есть. Ну или как вариант, если на кассе стоит например Iiko Front (прилажуха для ресторанных касс), к ней атол подключен. Можно было бы запилить плагин к Iiko Front (это из личного опыта), так же с http интерфейсом для принятия команд.

Comment: Павел, а такая схема будет работать с Сигма 7/10 у них закрытое ПО, но при этом через сервисные коды как-то обходят эту блокировку, знаете об этом что-нибудь?

Comment: хм, ну это сложный вопрос. Не сталкивался. Нужно копать возможности интеграции с  тем ПО, которые стоит на этом терминале.